# Warning in case of ARC?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I am using the following lines of code..

```
    NSArray *emailArray = (__bridge NSArray *)ABMultiValueCopyArrayOfAllValues(emailProperty);
```

and I am using ARC , but now when analyze this it gives me a warning that "Potential leak of object emailArray"...

how can I resolve this..? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to use `__bridge_transfer` in this case since you want to transfer ownership of the copied array to your `NSArray`:

```
NSArray *emailArray = (__bridge_transfer NSArray *)ABMultiValueCopyArrayOfAllValues(emailProperty);
```

Comment: Or, alternatively, `CFBridgingRelease()`.